# Using Handler with Postdelayed to update Notification

Tags: java, android

Am trying yo use a `TimerTask()` with a `Handler()` associated with a postDelayed to update my notification running the method task every 1sec but I seem to be hitting a wall implementing it properly from the looks of things.
Here is a sample from my code:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateNotificationUi();
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
}
```

Then `updateNotificationUi()` method code:

```
private void updateNotificationUi() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(isRunning) {

  mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text").setContentText("This value here updates every 1 sec").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 mNotifyManager.notify(notificationID, mNotificationBuilder.build());


            }
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

The error I get when running my app is `12-22 07:37:20.556: E/AndroidRuntime(6555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there is a more elegant solution

You could define a Handler and a Runnable as global variables like this (notice the "postDelayed" inside the runnable):

```
Handler myHandler;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(isRunning) {

           mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text").setContentText("This value here updates every 1 sec").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

           mNotifyManager.notify(notificationID, mNotificationBuilder.build());

           myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    }

};

...
```

And then in your method start the loop:

```
private void updateNotificationUi() {

    myHandler = new Handler();

    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

Probably you will need a  stop condition too, maybe a boolean flag arroung "postDelayed" inside runnable. Something like this:

```
if(shouldContinueLooping){
    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `runnable` should be declared as `final`

Answer (score 1):

try calling your handler like this: (googling a little bit more could have helped)

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(isRunning) {

  mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text").setContentText("This value here updates every 1 sec").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 mNotifyManager.notify(notificationID, mNotificationBuilder.build());


            }
        }

    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't build `mNotificationBuilder` inside a thread without using the `UI thread`. same goes for `AlertDialogs`.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare).